Blazor Web App using Azure B2C calling an external API also using Azure B2C .Net 8
Im trying to move my Blazor project from .net 6 to 8 and go from WASM to a Blazor Web App so i can use interactive rendering and keep within .net support. My current client uses the following code to attach the token in a custom message handler and i inject the httpclient on the components.
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();


builder.Services.AddHttpClient("API", client =>
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7191"))
.AddHttpMessageHandler<CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler>();


builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>
   ().CreateClient("API"));

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://address.here/API.Access");
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "appRole";
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount,
    CustomAccountFactory>();


My Custom message handler contains the following:
public class CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler : AuthorizationMessageHandler
{
    public CustomAuthorizationMessageHandler(IAccessTokenProvider provider,
        NavigationManager navigationManager)
        : base(provider, navigationManager)
    {
        ConfigureHandler(
           authorizedUrls: new[] { "https://localhost:7191", "https://other.address.com" });

    }
}


If i do this in the Client side of a Blazor Web App then the baseurl is null, I have tried creating a named httpclient but this is also the same result.
If i move this to the Server side and place it in the program.cs then it is unable to resolve due to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.IAccessTokenProvider not being available.
How can i get the token on the Server side and add it to the httpclient or is there a way to set the Web App to use the client side to create the httpclient for my external calls?

Try using a Server-Side HttpClient, Pass the Token from Client to Server, Configure the HttpClient on the Server and configure CORS

Do you have any example of how to achieve this, I know how to make the server side client and add cors but I am unable to find a way to pass the token from the client back to the server?
